# Injecting dependencies into INSTALLED_APPs from reusable app

Tags: django, dependency-injection

I've recently been spinning a collection of Django apps into a namespace so that we can reuse them for multiple deployments, with different settings, media files, etc. The core of this has worked well. We can make a new Django project, and include all the apps (from our namespace) that we want in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

The problem I'm trying to fix is that we also have to explicitly include the Django apps that our namespaced apps depend on. Eg, where we currently need:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'import_export',
    'rest_framework',
    'reversion',
    'crispy_forms',

    'our_namespace.our_app',
]
```

I would like to be able to reduce this to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'our_namespace.our_app',  # brings all its dependencies with it
]
```

Other settings are easier to handle, but injecting into `INSTALLED_APPS` seems hard. Doing it from `AppConfig.ready()` doesn't seem to work because —if for no other reason— that [only runs after models have imported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded) (which is commonly too late).

What are my options here? Am I just being too lazy this time?

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have seen used is [this one, by Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/0feb9902733dfd80d0c6b33d4d6d4aa45c9e4509/mezzanine/utils/conf.py#L39-L48), which requires you to call a method at the bottom of a project's settings file:

```
try:
    from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
```

If you then look at what `set_dynamic_settings` does (see link above), it inspects the settings defined so far and modifies where appropriate - including making changes to `INSTALLED_APPS`, e.g.:

```
def set_dynamic_settings(s):
    for app in required_apps:   # Where required_apps is a list if apps you need
        if app not in s["INSTALLED_APPS"]:
            s["INSTALLED_APPS"].append(app)
```

This is the only way I know to do this sort of thing. Trying to do it from within your own app (i.e., without adding any other code to the settings file) will not work, because Django will already have initialised the settings object by the time it loads your app.